# Como pegar o valor anterior ao MAX no SQL?

Tags: sql

Como posso obter o valor  anterior ao `MAX` no SQL?

Tentei `MAX -1` porém não deu certo, pois os valores da coluna que quero selecionar o valor anterior ao `MAX` não estão em ordem crescente.

Comment: Olá @AmandaLima, você poderia mostrar o SQL que você tentou fazer? Assim fica mais fácil ajudar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O conceito de anterior pode ser relativo. Eu acho que isto resolve o que você quer:

```
SELECT MAX(coluna) FROM tabela WHERE coluna NOT IN (SELECT MAX(coluna) FROM tabela)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/MaxMax.sql).

Você faz uma busca pelo máximo e depois faz outra busca no todo sem o que encontrou, assim o novo máximo será o anterior.

Comment: Exatamente o que eu queria!! Obrigada!!!